# Setting WebRTC stream in HTML5 video element sometimes shows no image and creates weird artifacts

Tags: javascript, html, stream, webrtc

I am making a small chatroulette clone where I have implemented a switch webcam feature. Most of the times it works, but sometimes I get no image at all including weird artifacts over whole page, not only video element.

**Image:** https://i.gyazo.com/87d089807c17314ff79cda2e8eaea454.png

**Video:** https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3h9E32u9L9aU0lZZ0l1bUd5bDQ/view

**Demo:** https://codepen.io/grymer/pen/gxWzvw

Sometimes when I change the camera, ie. re-setting the video.srcObject, I get no image at all and diagonal black lines becomes visible overall the page.

This looks like a bug in Chrome. I've put together a small sample for anyone with two webcams to test (I have one real webcam and one [virtual](https://manycam.com/)).

**EDIT**: Updated demo. I'm logging all events on the video element.
When everything is working like expected, I receive these events:

- event: emptied
- event: loadstart
- event: durationchange
- event: loadedmetadata
- event: loadeddata
- event: canplay
- event: canplaythrough

When I get no image, these events have been execute:

- event: emptied
- event: loadstart

*So why does it stop at loadstart?*

Here are the demo source: 
**stackoverflow code snippets is not working with webrtc apparently. Go to codepen link**

```js
let deviceIds, currentDeviceId,
  videoEl = document.getElementById('video'),
  buttonEl = document.getElementById('button');

buttonEl.addEventListener('click', () => getUserMedia())
navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices().then(devices => {

  // get all video inputs
  deviceIds = devices.filter(device => device.kind === 'videoinput').map(device => device.deviceId);
  currentDeviceId = deviceIds.length > 0 ? 0 : -1;
}).then(() => {
  getUserMedia();
});

function getUserMedia() {
  const constraints = {
    audio: true,
    video: {
      deviceId: deviceIds[currentDeviceId]
    }
  };
  currentDeviceId = currentDeviceId === 0 ? 1 : 0;
  navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints).then(stream => {
    videoEl.srcObject = null;
    videoEl.srcObject = stream;
  });
}
```

```css
body {
  background: black;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<video id="video" width=200 height=200></video>
<button id="button">change</button>
<p>You need two webcams for this demo.</p>
```

Comment: add a `.catch(e => console.error(e))` to the getUserMedia call. Possibly the device can not be opened yet which if I recall correctly results in a TrackStartError

Comment: you might also want to stop all tracks of the current video object, i.e. `videoEl.srcObject.getTracks.forEach(t => t.stop())`

Comment: @PhilippHancke Stopping the tracks seems to work! Add it as answer and I'll mark it as correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a `.catch(e => console.error(e))` to the getUserMedia call. Possibly the device can not be opened yet which if I recall correctly results in a TrackStartError.

You might also want to stop all tracks of the current video object, i.e. `videoEl.srcObject.getTracks.forEach(t => t.stop())`

to avoid opening the device too often.